# case_when and grepl to mutate a new variable and take certain character strings

Tags: r

I have messy data (results) and I want to create a data frame where only certain values are taken from this list of results and the others are left blank:

```
results <- c("500",
             "500.0",
             "60",
             "60.0",
             "UNKNOWN",
             "450Other",
             "300-301",
             "ZZZ 12", "800/900", "500WWW500")

df <- data.frame(MIX = results, DESIRED = c("500",
                                            "500.0",
                                            "60",
                                            "60.0",
                                            "UNKNOWN",
                                            "",
                                            "",
                                            "","",""))
```

I would think I need to use case_when and grepl to do this but I'm not sure how to use REGEX well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep either integers or decimal numbers along with `"UNKOWN"`, we can use `grepl` as :

```
df <- data.frame(MIX = results, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$output <- df$MIX
df$output[!(grepl('^\\d+\\.?\\d+?$', df$MIX) | df$MIX == 'UNKNOWN')] <- ''

df
#         MIX  output
#1        500     500
#2      500.0   500.0
#3         60      60
#4       60.0    60.0
#5    UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
#6   450Other        
#7    300-301        
#8     ZZZ 12        
#9    800/900        
#10 500WWW500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with case_when:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(MIX = results, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(DESIRED = case_when(str_detect(MIX, '^\\d+\\.?\\d+?$|UNKNOWN') ~ MIX, 
                             TRUE ~ ''))
```